# Помогите разобраться с плагином загрузки на jquery fileupload

Tags: jquery, fileupload, javascript

В файле "upload.php" при отправки файла имя изменяется при помощи

```
$new_name = rand(3, 9). $_FILES['upl']['name'];
```

на "произвольное число" + "имя файла". Необходимо чтобы в конце вместе со статусом

```
 echo '{"status":"success"}';
```

передавалось имя или, к примеру, передавался параметр

```
echo '{"status":"success", "param":"new_name" }';
```

И появлялась надпись на экране (script.js) :

```
if(progress == 100){ alert (new_name);}
```

Не могу понять к какой переменной или объекту потом обратиться в файле script.js, чтобы вывести alert (new_name). Код скопировал от сюда:
Источник http://www.codeharmony.ru/materials/143
Архив: http://www.codeharmony.ru/demo/2014/01/06/code.rar

**Обновление**

Не могу понять к какой переменной или объекту потом обратиться в файле script.js, чтобы вывести alert(new_name)?

Comment: а что мешает ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#upload').fileupload({
    ....
    success: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

console:

```
0: "{"status":"success"}", 
1: "success"
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 2):

объект который возвращает .fileupload() это штука типа promise, вы можете сделать

```
.success(function(data) {
    /тут ваша обработка, ответ в data/ 
})
```

После `.fileupload({.....}).success(handler);` handler - ваша функция обработки ответа.

Comment: Не совсем понял куда нужно добавить?

Comment: после `.fileupload({.....}).success(handler);` handler - ваша функция обработки ответа,

Comment: Не могу понять. Пробовал разные комбинации
.success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {/* ... */});
и прочее, ничего не работает.
Можете подробнее написать как вызвать полученные данные через alert()?